# Where can I find the identity packages in VS 2017?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I have tried a lot to find an identity package in VS 2017. I have tried by right clicking on `project`, in `Manage nuGET packages`, but I am unable to find packages.

Answer (score 0):

```
On Manage nuGet Packages search for Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core
```

or

In package manager

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core
```

Comment: still can't find

Comment: can you share what package source are you using? you can do that from `Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Settings > Sources`. Also, what do you see when you do any search?